# Deleting entire folder in Visual Studio Post-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, post-build-event

I'm trying to delete a folder in my output directory using the following command line:

```
del /F "$(TargetDir)Content\"
```

Tho I always end up exiting with error code 1. I've tried several different ways, without /F, with/without slash both before and after, etc.

```
Error   1   The command "del /F "E:\proj\bin\Windows\Debug\Content\"" exited with code 1.
```

There are a lot of questions regarding deleting files in post-build event command lines in visual studio, which works fine, but I can't seem to delete a folder without getting code 1.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you set `Tools.Options.Projects and Solutions.Build and Run.Log verbosity = Diagnostic` and had a look in the log file?

Comment: You probably need to add /Q to turn off the "are you sure" prompt.  If you want to delete the folder itself as well as the contents of the folder you should use RD not DEL.

Comment: Thanks, RD /S /Q worked, should have written it as answer! Tried diagnostic and it did show the Y/N dialog, adding /Q removed the error but the folder still wasn't being deleted, seems I was using the wrong command for folders.. Tried deltree but it seems that command doesn't exist anymore so I thought del was the correct command.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
RD /S /Q "Full Path of Folder"
```

In your case:

```
RD /S /Q "$(TargetDir)Content\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Browse to the same folder using Command Prompt, and then run that command and see what the actual error is. Might be permissions or something is in use.

Comment: It did help me find that I needed a /Q command, which removed the error, but the folder still wasn't being deleted. RD /S /Q was the correct command to use for folders it seems.